# How to get complete thread dump from beginning of application?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class CheckResults {
   private int sheepCount = 0;
   private void incrementAndReport() {
      synchronized(this) {
         System.out.print((++sheepCount)+" ");
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ExecutorService service = null;
      try {
         service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
         var manager = new CheckResults();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            service.submit(() -> manager.incrementAndReport());
      } finally {
         if(service != null) service.shutdown();
      }
   }
}
```

This simply prints

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Now before I go to visualVM or other tool, the program gets terminated.
So what is the best way to get the complete dump of the threads which would be Waiting/Running etc..It would help me understanding/validating my multithreading models.
This may be a trivial question but I could not find a good write up or help.

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to add a `static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.out);` and `sc.nextLine();` before the `for` loop and in the `incrementAndReport()` method, so your process will wait until you press <Enter> several times.

Comment: Yes but that may not include the objects and locks a thread would be waiting for or other JVM info as in a thread dump.

Comment: Sure, but that will give you time to start VisualVM and take a thread dump, proceed by one step, take the next thread dump and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but looking for some automated way

Comment: Are you trying to get a thread dump after each task is submitted? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, it is like getting the complete trace of the threads with VM infos and thread states like waiting/runnable parked etc..as the application proceeds

Comment: The more thread dumping you do, the more you are going to affect the running threads and change the behavior of the problem.  Also, `System.out.println()` is a synchronous call meaning the more calls you make to it, the less your threads are going to run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear, but I gather you want multiple thread dumps, taken as your app proceeds.

Write a thread dump routine. Perhaps like this:

```java
    // `threadDump` method taken from: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump
    private static String threadDump ( boolean lockedMonitors , boolean lockedSynchronizers )
    {
        StringBuffer threadDump = new StringBuffer( System.lineSeparator() );
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        for ( ThreadInfo threadInfo : threadMXBean.dumpAllThreads( lockedMonitors , lockedSynchronizers ) )
        {
            String message = "Thread: " + threadInfo.getThreadId() + " | " + threadInfo.getThreadName();
            threadDump.append( message ).append( System.lineSeparator() );
//            threadDump.append( threadInfo.toString() );
        }
        return threadDump.toString();
    }
```

Call that routine within your code at appropriate points. I’m guessing you want to capture the thread dump after each task is submitted.

```java
      ExecutorService service = null;
      try {
         service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
         var manager = new CheckResults();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
            service.submit(() -> manager.incrementAndReport());
            String threadReport = Whatever.threadDump() ; // Do what you want with the string, log it, dump it to console, etc.
         }
      } finally {
         if(service != null) service.shutdown();
      }
```

Or perhaps you want to call the thread dump routine within the code of your task submitted to the executor service.

```java
      ExecutorService service = null;
      try {
         service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
         var manager = new CheckResults();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
            service.submit
            (
                () -> 
                {
                    manager.incrementAndReport();
                    String threadReport = Whatever.threadDump() ; // Do what you want with the string, log it, dump it to console, etc.
                }
            );
         }
      } finally {
         if(service != null) service.shutdown();
      }
```